# Any advice to better optimize scrolling code?

Tags: support, source-code, osx

At [Why are my sparks not animating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902831/why-are-my-sparks-not-animating), I have what looks on Mountain Lion like a non-scrolling area of code (without scrollbars until one hovers/scrolls): there are two JavaScript functions included, and then a third which is 'below the fold' as far as scrolling goes, again for Mountain Lion (other OS'es may not exhibit this).

When I first posted this, I wondered, 'How did I leave out the third function?' and then went to edit and found that the third function was there. It was just neatly cut off, and I would forgive someone who made a casual glance at my screen and failed to see that there was a third function.

[image]

Is there any kind of option or convention to say, 'If you're on Mountain Lion, please keep scrolling down?' Would it be helpful, for instance, after the last line of code to put a line that says '--MORE--' or '--More (please scroll down)--' or something like this?

Any conventions or advice would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, this actually is about SO. Thanks for the screenshot, @Arjan!

Comment: Tagged safari + osx, since I *assume* this is specific to that browser and OS - if someone can confirm that this *doesn't* happen in other browsers on OSX, would appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks, @Arjan - retagged (again). That's... kinda stupid, considering it's expected to be under the control of the site.

Comment: Related: [Lion's scrollbar doesn't appear on long code boxes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133113/134300)

Comment: @Shog9 I have the same effect using Chrome on Mountain Lion. It's actually and OS issue and not so much an SO issue. As mentioned by Arjan in his answer it can be disabled at OS level.

Comment: I guess that's indeed a dupe, @Jeremy?

Comment: @Diago It can (and should) also be disabled by Stack Exchange. I like Lion's behaviour in some cases, but it doesn't make *any sense* for embedded scrollable blocks like this. Besides, most visitors are not going to change their OS setting and may not realize what's going on. Stack Exchange should override this for code blocks.

Comment: @Arjan Maybe, but I was reluctant to vote because one could also see this as a follow-up to that post: if Stack Exchange isn't going to deal with this as a platform, how should I deal with it as a user?

Comment: OmniWeb on Lion does not display this issue.

Comment: (Agreed, @Jeremy, seeing you not voting to close, made me kind of think the same after a while...)

Comment: @JeremyBanks I disagree. I know how my OS and browser works and I instinctively know what to do, although it took time to learn. I am 100% willing to accept that there are people who prefer it to work differently, and I respect that. I would not support changing it, but would also not oppose it.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. It doesn't fix it. And I'm not personally inclined to do extra homework to workaround any host OS's limitations so that my code quote, which appeared to represent the whole picture above the fold, did not in fact appear to have a fold.

Answer (score 2):

I would delete anything from a post that is specific to the OS that some user might be using when viewing it.

Also note that things look different on mobile too, on which code blocks are not limited in height (and which don't get horizontal scrollbars either, but wrap lines instead):

[image]

(Note that you can easily disable the OS X default, to make it always show scrollbars.)